# Changing HTML5 text from JSON url getting error

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, html

I have a problem getting content and replacing the text using Reddit's subreddit Shower thoughts for data. What I'm trying to do is replace the h1 text with ID title to one from the JSON file but instead i get:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number at the var thought.

This is my javascript file for changing the text

```
<script>
      $.ajax({
        url: 'https://www.reddit.com/r/showerthoughts/top.json',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function( data )
        {
            var thought = data.children.0.data.title ;
            var author = data.children.'0'.data.author ;
    
            $('#title').text( thought );
        }
    });

  </script>
```

This is the HTML file that has the title.

```
 <body>
    <h1 class="title" id="title">Hello ! It's me</h1>
    <h5 class="author">- author</h5>
    <video autoplay loop poster="forest.jpeg" id="bgvid" controls muted>
        <source src="walk.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to access an array element, you'll have to use bracket notation like so:

```
var thought = data.children[0].data.title;
var author = data.children[0].data.author;
```

EDIT, This should work. You will receive a response object, not the data itself. The data can be found at `response.data`:

```
<script>
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://www.reddit.com/r/showerthoughts/top.json',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response)
        {
            var thought = response.data.children[0].data.title ;
            var author = response.data.children[0].data.author ;

            $('#title').text(thought);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: json['data']['children'][0]['data']['title'] This is what i get in the braincast json editor

Comment: What do you get in your console if you do the following: `console.log(data);` EDIT: I've found your issue, please see my edited post

Answer (score 0):

You can't do `data.children.0`, use `data.children[0]`. Anything after a dot has to be a valid identifier, and they cannot start with numbers.

See [What characters are valid for JavaScript variable names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661197/what-characters-are-valid-for-javascript-variable-names)